# Error: Target CPU does not support ARM mode

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cortex-m, codesourcery

I'm trying to cross=compile a simple program with inline assembly for a variety of ARM processors. It contains the assembly instruction QSUB which according to [this document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidceh.html) is both a valid ARM and Thumb-2 instruction.

This compiles fine for me when building for a cortex-a8.

I get the compile error in the title when I try building for a cortex-m3 and can't figure out why.  I attempted to force thumb mode with the compiler switch -mthumb, and then the error changes to "selected processor does not support thumb mode." I'm a bit confused because cortex-m3 does in fact support thumb mode.

Here's the compile options I'm using with codesourcery's gcc:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -o a.out -lm -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3
```

Comment: Just something to try, sometimes gcc can be picky about option order, try setting the CPU type _before_ setting thumb mode. (`-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb`) Possibly move both before even helloworld.c

Comment: thumb (not thumb2) is the most portable across the arm family.  I cant find a concrete list from arm but it appears that the cortex-m4 is an ARMv7E-M and the cortex-m3 is an ARMv7-M.  looking at a current ARMv7-M ARM, it shows the QSUB being ARMv7E-M specific not all ARMv7 cores. (older armv7-m arm's did show QSUB as simply an ARMv7-M instruction, very confusing).  Note the Cortex-m0 and -m1 are armv6 based and have a very limited thumb2 instruction set...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QSUB` is not mentioned in ARM's ["Cortex-M3 Devices Generic User Guide" (Document DUI0552A)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/DUI0552A_cortex_m3_dgug.pdf).

Additionally, TI's ["Cortex-M3/M4F Instruction Set, TECHNICAL USER'S MANUAL"](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu159a/spmu159a.pdf) indicates that  `QSUB` is not supported on the Cortex-M3.

I think you're just going to have to believe what GCC is telling you...

Comment: Thank you, i just found this independently as well. I guess I'll have to find another way to go about my saturation arithemetic

Comment: @BrandonYates from the linked page: "For the ARMv7-M architecture, they are only available in an ARMv7E-M implementation". ARMv7E-M is implemented in Cortex-M4 (M3 is just ARMv7-M). Maybe check out if the CMSIS-DSP library does what you need; it supports both M3 and M4.

Answer (score 4):

In accordance with **TI** the best **gcc** flags for **cortex-a8** are

```
-march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cortex-A8